# Force Ubuntu to use ONLY Noto fonts

Tags: fonts

So recently I've had lots of problems with merging all Noto fonts into one font so that I don't need to go through the hassle of adding every single Noto fonts. However, this one font WenQuanYi Zen Hei keeps taking up Noto CJK's priority. Question is can someone write a `fonts.conf` to use ONLY Noto fonts?

Comment: Uninstall the `fonts-wqy-zenhei` package?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson doesn't work, system straight up said missing fonts

Comment: Then you'd better explain how you installed zenhei.

Comment: `sudo apt install wqy-zenhei`

Comment: AFAIK there is no `wqy-zenhei` package in the Ubuntu archive. Its name is `fonts-wqy-zenhei`.

Comment: Yes thanks for correcting me. It is `fonts-wqy-zenhei`

Comment: And in that case you ought to be able to do `sudo apt purge fonts-wqy-zenhei`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Sorry for late reply. That didn't work. System would just not use Noto CJK.

Comment: It's unclear to me why you did what you did, considering that the `fonts-noto-cjk` package is installed in Ubuntu by default. There is also the file `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/64-language-selector-prefer.conf` which gives the Noto CJK fonts sufficient precedence by default.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I have no idea either, that's why I'm making a question here

Comment: That's fine, but I think you need to explain better what you did - and why - to get meaningful help. As from Ubuntu 16.04, Noto Sans CJK is default Chinese font on all desktop installations via the `fonts-noto-cjk` package. Which Ubuntu version are you on?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Well, now that everything is in this section, I don't think I need to update any further. Anyway, I put all Noto fonts info `fonts.conf` under `.config/fontconfig`. Will update.